# Show Bootstrap modal to right most side

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

We use Javascript to show a Bootstrap modal, what Javascript options should be added to make the Bootstrap modal show to the rightmost side of the page?

This is my code to show a modal (element is the modal)

`$(element).modal('show');`

What can be added to make the modal show to rightmost side?

Comment: Why dont you go with css way?? Did you find any class like this ```class="modal-dialog"``` in your html?/

Answer (score 2):

You can use default bootstrap class in your modal to move the modal to the right..

Just add **mr-0** to the `modal-dialog` like, `<div class="modal-dialog mr-0">`

Orelse,
You can use css with **margin-right: 0** to `modal-dialog`..

```
.modal-dialog {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Working **example**: https://www.bootply.com/IhPyvzUhJS

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like following in your css file

```
.modal-dialog {
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-left: 50%;
}
```

Adjust `margin-left:` as per your requirement